# docker container not removing from docker

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I am trying to remove container but when i run `docker-compose rm` ,runs fine but when i run `docker ps` then again it shows container:

```
root@datafinance:/tmp# docker-compose rm
Going to remove tmp_zookeeper_1_31dd890a1cbf
Are you sure? [yN] y
Removing tmp_zookeeper_1_31dd890a1cbf ... done
root@datafinance:/tmp# docker ps
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE                              COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS              PORTS               NAMES
03b08e4ef0b3        confluentinc/cp-zookeeper:latest   "/etc/confluent/dock…"   14 hours ago        Up 14 hours                             docker_c_zookeeper_1_7c953dce7d69
```

Comment: `docker-compose ps` to confirm if this container really come from compose up

Comment: @atline No there is not container after using `docker-compose ps`

Comment: But when i use `docker-compose up -d` it shows that port already in use.


ERROR: for tmp_zookeeper_1_effa39f3f138  Cannot start service zookeeper: b'driver failed programming external connectivity on endpoint tmp_zookeeper_1_bb7bf7c83720 (fed37bec97b19d6c46dc993bf63ab7070d36ee644391e113fb2cc1113516fb70): Error starting userland proxy: listen tcp 0.0.0.0:32181: bind: address already in use'

Comment: Remove all containers `docker rm -f $(docker ps -qa)` or `netstat -oanltp | grep 32181` to see what really occupy the port.

Comment: @atline after running `docker rm -f $(docker ps -qa)` i am getting following error:

Error response from daemon: Could not kill running container 03b08e4ef0b3fa6329bee2c42a39a8a83b5db28809d7b02d75d9826dfe14846e, cannot remove - Cannot kill container 03b08e4ef0b3fa6329bee2c42a39a8a83b5db28809d7b02d75d9826dfe14846e: unknown error after kill: runc did not terminate sucessfully: container_linux.go:388: signaling init process caused "permission denied"
: unknown

Comment: Restart your docker service or just reboot your computer if you did not set --restart, then execute above command again.

Comment: @atline you are saying `service docker restart`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `docker-compose ps`, it will show the container which only launched by `docker-compose up`. If it shows there is no container, then this means this container was not launched by this `docker-compose.yaml`.

And `Error starting userland proxy: listen tcp 0.0.0.0:32181: bind: address already in use'` means the port 32181 is occupied either by `other docker container` or `other process`. You could use `docker rm -f $(docker ps -qa)` to delete all containers or more you can use `netstat -oanltp | grep 32181` to find which process really occupy 32181.

Finally, if for any reason you did not able to delete container as you said, you can just use `service docker restart` or `systemctl restart docker` to make all container down. Then repeat above `docker rm xxx`.

With above steps, you can use `docker compose up -d` to use your service now.

Comment: Thanks This works fine for me. But this needs to restart system using `reboot`

Answer (score 1):

try this :

```
docker rm -f 03b08e4ef0b3
```

**DANGER**

you may also try this, but be aware that will delete everything (Containers, Images, Networks, ....)

```
docker system prune -a -f
```

when all not helped your last resort is to restart Docker daemon

```
service docker restart
```

and then repeat the steps...

Comment: I am getting following error:

Error response from daemon: Could not kill running container 03b08e4ef0b3fa6329bee2c42a39a8a83b5db28809d7b02d75d9826dfe14846e, cannot remove - Cannot kill container 03b08e4ef0b3fa6329bee2c42a39a8a83b5db28809d7b02d75d9826dfe14846e: unknown error after kill: runc did not terminate sucessfully: container_linux.go:388: signaling init process caused "permission denied"
: unknown

Answer (score 0):

I think what you are looking for is :

```
docker-compose down
```

which removes the containers after stopping them according to [this](https://nickjanetakis.com/blog/docker-tip-45-docker-compose-stop-vs-down).

According to [this](https://docs.docker.com/compose/reference/rm/), docker-compose rm removes the "stopped" containers. If your container(s) are running, I think it won't remove to prevent accidents.

Comment: root@datafinance:/tmp# docker-compose down
Removing network tmp_default
WARNING: Network tmp_default not found.